# Do Kubernetes http probes follow redirects?

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

According to the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

> Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates
> success. Any other code indicates failure.

so if the container returns `301` for the probe, the probe should succeed. But I have a container in which it's not the case. With CURL I get `301`, but probe fails with `503`. The target of the redirect is not available.

Tested in Openshift 3.11 with the following probe:

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: 'redirect'
              image: ngingx
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
              livenessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: /
                  port: http
              readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: /
                  port: http
```

Comment: Probably your application needs more time to start. Try increasing initialDelaySeconds in probe settings.

Comment: @VasiliAngapov delay is not a problem, application starts immediately.

Comment: Can you add your probe configuration and how you tested using CURL

Comment: Could you provide some details about your environment (local, cloud, if yes which one). Your configuration would be also helpful. What is error message? Any suspecting entries in the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic was already rised in Github - [kubelet's httpProbe follow redirects](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73172)

According to `@thockin` tests in [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73172#issuecomment-472499665), current `probes` configuration  allows `HTTP probes` to redirecting and it's current behavior.

> c) fix docs and follow redirects wherever they lead (current behavior)

I've check changelogs and this behavior was not changed.

In addition you can check [this thread](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/3441#issuecomment-633154665) with similar issue, when response is `301`.